# SharePoint Provider Hosted app deployment

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, sharepoint-2013, octopus-deploy, provider-hosted

I am new to sharepoint so please bear with me! I have completed a provider hosted application that we will be hosting on premise! One of our requirements is that all apps are ran through TeamCity for build and Octopus for deployment and we use GIT for Source control. I have figured out how to get team city to build my MVC portion of the provider hosted app and got octopus to deploy it, my problem is now how to get he SharePoint part of the app to be automated like that. WHat I mean is now I have to click on publish in visual studio and have it create a .app file and I then have to give that to our operations guys who then upload it to our internal app catalog! is there a way to get TeamCity to create the .App file and then have Octopus deploy it to the Sharepoint Catalog?

Comment: Wow I guess this is a tough one ! Well how about does anyone know of a way to get team city to create the .app file using MSBuild commands?

Comment: AS it turns out this is doable, I have figured it out, its is very complicated and requires the site to have SideLoading enabled where the app will be deployed! this is a security concern where I work so we will not be perusing this further if someone needs this I will put together a tutorial and post it soon